# How to extend list of objects to automatically update property based on position in list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I have a class Car like this:

```
class car 
{
string model;
int position;
}
```

Position is a number from 1 to n, which basically reflects position in the list. 
if I have two cars in list they will have positions 1 2.
Now, I'd like to reorder those cars in list in the UI and reflect change in the property for later uses.
So I have a table with several rows:

```
Car1  1  
Car2  2     
Car3  3   
Car4  4
```

Now, If I want to reorder items I can drag Car4 and place it at position 2 (right after Car1).
So, my positions will be as follows:

```
Car1  1  
Car4  2     
Car2  3   
Car3  4
```

So, what I want to do is to update one item in the list, and all other items will be automatically updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like this:

```
BindingList<car> list = new BindingList<car>();
list.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(list_ListChanged);

void list_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            list[e.OldIndex].position = e.NewIndex;
            for (int i = e.NewIndex; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                list[i].position = i+1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The best approach in situations like that is to not *store* the position at all, but *imply* it instead. Keep the `model` attribute, and drop the `position`. Whenever you need the position, or a list of all elements paired with their positions, you can use LINQ's `Select` overload that takes the index:

```
var carsWithIndex = carList.Select((car, index) => new {
    Car = car
,   Index = index
}).ToList();
```

Now you have a list of objects that have two attributes:

- `Car` - the `car` element of the list, and the
- `Index` - the index of the corresponding `car` in the `carList`.

You can re-order the elements of `carList` at will; the implied index is going to change each time that you re-order. Each time you need the index, run the above LINQ expression to pair each `car` with its new index.